# Finding the constants in sigmoid equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, curves, regression, regression-analysis

We have a sigmoid with the form

$$y=\frac{e^{x+a}}{b+ce^{x+d}}$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are real constants.

We have known points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),(x_4,y_4)$ all satisfying the equation of the sigmoid, and we need to find the constants $a,b,c,d$.

---

So is it possible to solve the following system for those constants:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y_1=\frac{e^{x_1+a}}{b+ce^{x_1+d}}\\ 
{}\\
y_2=\frac{e^{x_2+a}}{b+ce^{x_2+d}}\\ 
{}\\
y_3=\frac{e^{x_3+a}}{b+ce^{x_3+d}}\\
{}\\
y_4=\frac{e^{x_4+a}}{b+ce^{x_4+d}} 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

---

In other words, we need to express $a,b,c,d$ in terms of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$.

---

Wolfram Alpha did not solve this problem as required. What I think, but not sure, that there exist infinitely many combinations of $a,b,c,d$ so that the given points lie on the sigmoid.

If that is the case, I need only one of those combinations.

---

Here is a clarification graph

[image]

---

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\frac{e^{x+a}}{b+ce^{x+d}}$$
$$e^{x+a}=e^ae^x\quad\text{and}\quad e^{x+d}=e^de^x$$
$$y=\frac{e^ae^{x}}{b+ce^de^{x}}=\frac{e^{x}}{be^{-a}+ce^{d-a}e^{x}}$$
Let $\quad B=be^{-a}\quad$ and $\quad C=ce^{d-a}$
$$y=\frac{e^{x}}{B+Ce^{x}}$$
Thus you have not four unknows $a,b,c,d$  but only two unknowns $B,C$.
This means that if a couple $B,C$ is solution they are an infinity of solutions for $a,b,c,d$ since $b=Be^a$ and $c=Ce^{a-d}$ . You can take arbitrary $a,d$.

This shows that the question is put on the wrong way.

With four given points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),(x_4,y_4)$ leading to four equations but only two unknows, in general the system has no exact solution.

Only two points are sufficient to find $B,C$ from 
$\quad\begin{cases}
y_1=\frac{e^{x_1}}{B+Ce^{x_1}}\\
y_2=\frac{e^{x_2}}{B+Ce^{x_2}}
\end{cases}$

I suppose that you can solve the linear system $\quad\begin{cases}
B+e^{x_1}C=\frac{e^{x_1}}{y_1}\\
B+e^{x_2}C=\frac{e^{x_2}}{y_1}
\end{cases}$

If ANY four points are given, the curve cannot fit exactly. One have to proceed with a regression method which will give be best approximates for $B,C$ according o some criteria of fitting. This can be easily carried out.

Please, reedit your question without ambiguity so that one can give you more help to correctly solve the problem.

In addition :

If the question specifies that four points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),(x_4,y_4)$ are given and that the function $y(x)$ must exactly fit, then four independant parameters $a,b,c,d$ are necessary.

An infinity of functions are likely to be convenient. For exemple :
$$y=a+\frac{e^{c\,x}}{b+d\,e^{c\,x}}$$
But I bet that this form of equation will not fully satisfy you. In the wording of the question they are not enough specifications about what is expected to chose an equation fully satisfying.

Comment: Thanks, it is very clear what you have said. But is it possible that we find some expressions for $y$ so that all four points satisfy $y$? Given that $\infty<x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$, $\infty<y_1<y_2<y_3<y_4$, the curve is always increasing, it is concave up in $(-\infty,x_2)$ and concave down in $(x_2,\infty)$, and it has a limit as $x$ tends to $\infty$. Any such function that satisfies these conditions is accepted. Thanks dear.

Comment: Sure it is possible. Many expressions for $y$ are possible. But your problem is not sufficiently defined to chose a convenient expression. Is $y$ tending to $0$ or to a small constant for $x$ tending to $-\infty$ ? Are the coordinates of the four points known with an infinite accuracy or are they real measurements ? Can you give a numerical example ?

Comment: I mentioned in my comment that $y$ has a limit as $x$ tends to $\infty$. See the given graph in my original post. THANKS DEAR :)

Comment: You don't understand. Of course $y$ has a limit as $x\to\infty$ and $y$ has another limit as $x\to-\infty$. But are those limits known (given) or not ? Anyways, the key point is fully explain in my answer : You give the coordinates of four points in order to fit a function involving only two independent parameters. The answer is THERE IS NO EXACT SOLUTION in general. Give only two points and there will be one exact solution.